# auto-repeat flag in a pack format string

Tags: python, pack

In php, unpack() has the "*" flag which means "repeat this format until the end of input". For example, this prints 97, 98, 99

```
$str = "abc";
$b = unpack("c*", $str);
print_r($b);
```

Is there something like this in python? Of course, I can do

```
str = "abc"
print struct.unpack("b" * len(str), str)
```

but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: JBernardo, you should consider moving this to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpack format characters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176354/unpack-format-characters-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such facility built into `struct.unpack`, but it is possible to define such a function:

```
import struct

def unpack(fmt, astr):
    """
    Return struct.unpack(fmt, astr) with the optional single * in fmt replaced with
    the appropriate number, given the length of astr.
    """
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/7867892/190597
    try:
        return struct.unpack(fmt, astr)
    except struct.error:
        flen = struct.calcsize(fmt.replace('*', ''))
        alen = len(astr)
        idx = fmt.find('*')
        before_char = fmt[idx-1]
        n = (alen-flen)/struct.calcsize(before_char)+1
        fmt = ''.join((fmt[:idx-1], str(n), before_char, fmt[idx+1:]))
        return struct.unpack(fmt, astr)

print(unpack('b*','abc'))
# (97, 98, 99)
```

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3.4 and later, you can use the new function [`struct.iter_unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.iter_unpack).

> `struct.iter_unpack(fmt, buffer)`
>
> Iteratively unpack from the buffer buffer according to the format string fmt. This function returns an iterator which will read equally-sized chunks from the buffer until all its contents have been consumed. The buffer’s size in bytes must be a multiple of the size required by the format, as reflected by calcsize().
> Each iteration yields a tuple as specified by the format string.

Let's say we want to unpack the array `b'\x01\x02\x03'*3` with the repeating format string `'<2sc'` (2 characters followed by a single character, repeat until done).

With `iter_unpack`, you can do the following:

```
>>> import struct
>>> some_bytes = b'\x01\x02\x03'*3
>>> fmt = '<2sc'
>>> 
>>> tuple(struct.iter_unpack(fmt, some_bytes))
((b'\x01\x02', b'\x03'), (b'\x01\x02', b'\x03'), (b'\x01\x02', b'\x03'))
```

If you want to un-nest this result, you can do so with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> tuple(chain.from_iterable(struct.iter_unpack(fmt, some_bytes)))
(b'\x01\x02', b'\x03', b'\x01\x02', b'\x03', b'\x01\x02', b'\x03')
```

Of course, you could just employ a nested comprehension to do the same thing.

```
>>> tuple(x for subtuple in struct.iter_unpack(fmt, some_bytes) for x in subtuple)
(b'\x01\x02', b'\x03', b'\x01\x02', b'\x03', b'\x01\x02', b'\x03')
```